# How to add bot to coversation in Circuit sandbox?

Tags: circuit-sdk

I had created bot app using Circuit SDK and got a sandbox in circuitsandbox.net. To create a bot application I went to "Manage Applications" -> "Custom Apps" and created a bot app. It works great but only way to add bot to conversation I found is to type his full mail in "Add Conversation" menu. Is it possible to found him like common user (searching by his name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots can be added via email as you noted, and not by its name. 
But the new way to add bots to conversations is via the sidebar. This will be available very shortly, probably in a week or two.

Comment: Is it available now? And if it's not, where I will be able to know that  it released?

Comment: Incoming webhook bots can now be added via this new sidebar as described at https://www.circuit.com/unifyportalfaqdetail?articleId=164448. But adding regular OAuth 2.0 Bots like this will be a bit longer. This should be advertised on the "Welcome Notes" of the Circuit webclient once available.